# No indentation in local ToC

Tags: indentation, titletoc

I do not want indentation on the local ToC. I am using the `titletoc` package, also I use `titlesec` and `titleref` packages.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titleref}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\newcommand{\localToC}{
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\noindent\rule{0.5\textwidth}{1.5pt}\vspace{3mm}}{\vspace{3mm}\noindent\rule{0.5\textwidth}{1.5pt}\vspace{10mm}}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{\oldchapter{#1}\localToC}

    \chapter{Chapter 1}
        \section{Section 1}
        \section{Section 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a complete minimal working example, i.e. some code that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, and illustrates the issue?

Comment: It is done, I updated the code.